# React form filtering not returning specific data from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, json

I have a search form that returns an object of data on submit.

I am trying to filter the data from an API using the submitted form data.

I'm doing this like so...

```
const { firstName, lastName, postcode } = formData

const filter = Object.values(values).filter((item) => {
      return (item.postcode !== null && item.postcode !== undefined && item.postcode.toLowerCase().trim() === postcode.toLowerCase().trim()) || (item.firstName !== null && item.firstName !== undefined && item.firstName.toLowerCase() === firstName.toLowerCase().trim()) || (item.lastName !== null && item.lastName !== undefined && item.lastName.toLowerCase() === lastName.toLowerCase().trim())
    });

console.log(filter)
```

The data submitted via the form looks like the following...

```
data {postcode: 'SA11 3FJ', firstName: 'Joe', lastName: 'Bloggs'}
```

The API contains only 1 entry matching the submitted data above and multiple other entries of different people with that same postcode.

However my filter method above returns all entries with the same postcode, instead of just only `{postcode: 'SA11 3FJ', firstName: 'Joe', lastName: 'Bloggs'}`.

How can I make this return only the searched for values.

A user should be able to submit only 1, 2 or all 3 values in the form.

Comment: you are shortcircuiting when you hit the first ||. so all matching the first condition returns. you might want to use an && instead.

Comment: When I use && I get an error saying can't convert null toLowerCase()  if not all fields have values.

Comment: Example: When I use && and only search for `firstName` I get this error `caught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase')`

Comment: `values.filter(item =>
  ((firstName && item.firstName?.toLowerCase() === firstName.toLowerCase()) || !firstName) &&
  ((lastName && item.lastName?.toLowerCase() === lastName.toLowerCase()) || !lastName) &&
  ((postcode && item.postcode?.toLowerCase().trim() === postcode.toLowerCase().trim()) || !postcode)
)`

Answer (score 0):

When checking if an object is undefined, it is sufficient to use the `==` operator and compare that object to `null`. So in your code when you do:

```
item.postcode !== null && item.postcode !== undefined
```

The above is equivalent to just doing

```
item.postcode != null
```

This is due to the rules of [loose equality](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-islooselyequal) which is the algorithm used for comparison with the `==` operator. See [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness)

---

To answer your question, instead of using `||` operator which short-circuits once the condition on the left-hand side is true, you should use the `&&` operator which only evaluates to true when all conditions are true.

Re-writing your filter, along with the suggestions above:

```
const filter = Object.values(values).filter((item) => {
    return item.postcode != null && item.postcode.toLowerCase().trim() === postcode.toLowerCase().trim() && item.firstName != null && item.firstName.toLowerCase() === firstName.toLowerCase().trim() && item.lastName != null && item.lastName.toLowerCase() === lastName.toLowerCase().trim()
});
```

Edit:

To avoid issues with null, you can use this more expanded form:

```
const filter = Object.values(values).filter((item) => {
    let matches = true;
    if (postcode != null) {
        matches = matches && item.postcode != null && item.postcode.toLowerCase() === postcode.toLowerCase().trim()
    }

    if (firstName != null) {
        matches = matches && item.firstName != null && item.firstName.toLowerCase() === firstName.toLowerCase().trim()
    }

    if (lastName != null) {
        matches = matches && item.lastName != null && item.lastName.toLowerCase() === lastName.toLowerCase().trim()
    }
    return matches;
});
```

Comment: Again this only works if all 3 values have been input. For example: A search on just the postcode returns an empty array, the same with just firstName or lastName

Comment: @i-am-niall i suggest you create a function which does filtering based on some if checks. check if all values are passed then consider an && and return. then check if 2 are not passed and so on

Comment: @i-am-niall it should be addressed in the new changes